# Queued Method invocation in its own thread with callbacks

Tags: c#, .net, queue

After asking a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517445/queued-method-invocation-in-its-own-thread) (thanks for the answers) I would like to add another Feature to the queue but unfortunately I have no idea how to implement this: I would like to add an optional callback to every added function. That callback should be called when this given function completed. How can I add this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a `BlockingCollection<Func<object>>`, create a class to hold the function to be executed and the optional callback:

```
class QueueItem
{
    public Func<object> FuncToExecute { get; set; }
    public Action OptionalCallback { get; set; }
}
```

Your method to add an item to the queue becomes:

```
void AddFunction(Func<object> functionToAdd, Action callback = null)
{
    Queue.Add(new QueueItem(functionToAdd, callback);
}
```

When you dequeue an item, execute the function, and then call the callback if it's not null:

```
public void ProcessQueue()
{
    QueueItem item;
    while (!IsCancelled && queue.TryTake(out item, Timeout.Infinite))
    {
        item.FuncToExecute();
        if (item.OptionalCallback != null)
        {
            item.OptionalCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

The above assumes that you're using the model I recommended in my answer to your linked question.